# ActionListener JTextField reset to 0

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

I have a `JButton` and I would like the score which is a `JTextField` to reset to 0 whenever it is pressed.

```
...
newGameButton.addActionListener(this);
...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    (add action here)
}
```

What would I need to do to reset the JTextField to 0? 
Do you guys know any good websites for learning GUI? 
Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: What's wrong with `score = 0; textField.setText(String.valueOf(score));`?

Comment: Besides that, this is an extremely poorly asked question without enough information(code) to help you solve your problem

Comment: @peeskillet How does the program know that I want score to change to 0 and not some other JTextFeild when an Action is preformed?

Comment: From the text field variable. Whatever text field you want, say `scoreTextField`. If you haven't given your text field a variable, then you need to do so.

Comment: @peekskillet, what is wrong, from a software designer view, is not to use MVC paradigm. I think everybody should learn good pratices from beginning. Your should modify the model "score" and bind it to the TextField. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/fxbest-1583679.html

Comment: @Ezequiel while I don't disagree with you (from a software designer view), for a beginner, especially with Swing, it is a little more complicated to fully understand how to use an MVC design pattern. Binds don't come as easily in Swing as they do in JavaFX

Comment: Look that tutorial for Swing Binding with NetBeans https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-binding.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace (add action here), with myTestField.setText("0"), or score = 0; myTestField.setText(score). Something along those lines.

The official Java tutorials are an excellent place to learn Swing and other related Java techs, it's quite good, so follow that link peeskillet gave you in the comments. There's some good books on Swing too, I would recommend Filthy Rich Clients.

Comment: Truly appreciate it !